# Can IntStream::noneMatch not evaluate the predicate on all the elements of the stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I read the Javadoc of [IntStream::noneMatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

It says :

> Returns whether no elements of this stream match the provided predicate. **May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result.** If the stream is empty then true is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

I was wondering if there's an actual scenario in which `noneMatch` will not evaluate the predicate on all the elements of the stream and return true (in the case where `noneMatch` returns false, it is clear that the predicate is only evaluated on elements until the first match is found).

The only scenario I could think of was that if the stream pipeline would have a filter whose predicate is the exact negative of the predicate of `noneMatch`, perhaps `noneMatch` would return true without testing any elements.

However, when tested with the following code :

```
boolean out = IntStream.range(1, 10000)
                  .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                  .peek(System.out::println)
                  .noneMatch(i -> i % 2 == 1);
System.out.println(out);
```

I get an output of even numbers starting from 2 to 9998:

```
2
4
6
...
9998
true
```

which means the entire stream was evaluated, even though the filter returns only even integers, while the predicate of `noneMatch` requires no odd integers to be found, so it should be able to return true without evaluating any elements.

So, when the Javadoc says `May not evaluate on all elements.`, does it only refer to the cases in which `noneMatch` returns false?

EDIT:

I just wanted to clarify that my question is **not** why the code I posted evaluates the entire stream. My question is whether there's a scenario in which `noneMatch` **returns *true* without evaluating the entire stream**.

Comment: Well, it *might* be the case that future versions can detect contradicting `Predicates`. Or maybe future APIs have a `Predicate.matchNone` constant which will be recognized when being passed to `Stream.filter`. Or it *might* recognize when a `map` operation has a function which does not depend on its input (in which case checking a single element would be enough to determine the entire result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so it should be able to return true without evaluating any elements

No, in order to check that *none* of the elements match, it has to check *everything*. In other words, if it returns `true` then it will definitely have looked at everything. To put it another way - your logic relied on what the predicate does, so how can it return without evaluating any elements, when that means the predicate would never be applied?

The only way it could return `true` without evaluating all elements would be if it could tell just by the *type* of the stream and something about the predicate. For example, if the stream "knew" that it was a stream of `UUID` references, and the predicate was "match strings" then it wouldn't need to evaluate things - but I doubt that there's anything that tries for that sort of optimization.

If (and only if) it finds something which *does* match the predicate, however, it can return `false` without looking at the rest of the items.

For example, if you change your code to:

```
boolean out = IntStream.range(1,10000)
               .peek(System.out::println)
               .noneMatch(i->i%4==3);
System.out.println(out);
```

then you'll get output of:

```
1
2
3
false
```

Comment: So, what you are saying is that `May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result.` applies only to the case where `noneMatch` returns false? The Javadoc doesn't say it explicitly, so I wondered if there may be cases where is returns true without evaluating all the elements.

Comment: @Eran: I've edited my answer with a *possible* scenario, but I don't think it's actually implemented, and certainly it doesn't apply to the example you gave.